# Jupyter notebook can't read ssl certificate files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed and configure jupyter notebook to run as a public server (with password). When I run `jupyter notebook` it tells me the `fullchain.pem` file does not exist.

```
(jupyter) rootadmin@ubuntu12:~/opensurfaces$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1769, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1485, in init_webapp
    max_buffer_size=self.max_buffer_size)
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/util.py", line 286, in __new__
    instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 191, in initialize
    read_chunk_size=chunk_size,
  File "/home/rootadmin/opensurfaces/jupyter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 134, in __init__
    'certfile "%s" does not exist' % self.ssl_options["certfile"]
ValueError: certfile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url/fullchain.pem" does not exist
```

In the `juputer_notebook_config.py` file, I have the following

```
## The full path to an SSL/TLS certificate file.
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url/fullchain.pem'
```

The file exists (at that exact location) with the following permissions

```
(jupyter) rootadmin@ubuntu12:/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       49 Mar 12 12:26 cert.pem -> ../../archive/my_website_url/cert9.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       50 Mar 12 12:26 chain.pem -> ../../archive/my_website_url/chain9.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       54 Mar 12 12:26 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/my_website_url/fullchain9.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       52 Mar 12 12:26 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/my_website_url/privkey9.pem
```

I can't read the file with my user (e.g. `nano fullchain.pem`) but I can read it using `sudo nano`. I guess I could copy the files to a location jupyter can read, but that seems a little silly.

How can I make jupyter notebook work?

*edit*: If I indeed simply copy the certificate files to a different location, it appears to work. Then I'm running into a different, and I think, unrelated problem. I made a separate question about [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657913/public-jupyter-notebook-is-running-on-computer-name-instead-of-computer-url)

Comment: Have you tried restricting the permissions on that file with `chmod 400 /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url/fullchain.pem`?

Comment: Yes, but now that I'm looking at it more closely, `chmod` doesn't appear to change the permissions at all. 400,755,500 it doesn't actually change?

Comment: Those a symlinks, so you are not showing the actual permissions. Use the `-L` option for `ls` to dereference symlinks.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks. Using `-L` I see it change. The error remains though.

Comment: You might also try the direct path to the cert rather than a symlink to see if that is the issue. If the symlink doesn't point to the right place for some reason then `os.path.exists` will return `False`, which is what tornado is doing when it errors: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/c50aed0f96d92f9b0ef4cd0837c0104f140ca77e/tornado/tcpserver.py#L132-L135

Comment: @hume I'm not very familiar with symlinks. How do I find the direct path?

Comment: Oh, and `nginx` is using  the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem`, from those exact locations without issue, i.e. I can actually visit the website it's running

Comment: `readlink -e /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url/fullchain.pem` should work:  https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink  Then you can try putting that path as `c.NotebookApp.certfile`

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because jupyter does not have sufficient permission to read the cert file.

To resolve this issue, use `chmod 755` to make sure all parent folders (/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url and ../../archive/my_website_url/fullchain9.pem) and certs are readable.

For example, run following commands:

`chmod 755 /etc`

`chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt`

`chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live`

`chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url`

`chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url/fullchain.pem`

`chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_url/privkey.pem`

`chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/archive`

`chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my_website_url`

`chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my_website_url/fullchain1.pem`

`chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my_website_url/privkey1.pem`

You can simply use `cat xxx.pem` without sudo to test. If you are able to get the content, jupyter notebook should be able to read them as well.